# Is there any example to filter data by model's field in vue

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, jhipster, spring-data-mongodb, quasar-framework

I am using [generator-jhipster-quasar](https://github.com/ctamisier/generator-jhipster-quasar) to maintain MongoDB data. I need to have a filter that applies the Criteria of user inputs.

Hence, users will put operators against fields of several types but mostly are String and DateTime ones. So there will be (orOperator, andOperator, lt, gt, between, ...etc).

So, is there any example ready to use which is having these requirements?

Comment: As Peter Malcovsky mentioned it, you could get some inspiration from JHipster entity filtering, although it uses JPA and so does not apply to MongoDb, at least the frontend part could be similar.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Let's see if there is a ready-to-use code for a more complete and professional filter/search method.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.